# getting different object size with different functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, size

Why this code snippet is giving different size in bytes with two different functions. I am using 32 bit version of python 2.7.3

1) with dictionaries:-

```
from sys import getsizeof
l = range(20)            
d = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(l)}    #creating a dict
d.__sizeof__()   #gives size in bytes 
508              #size of dictionary 'd' in bytes

getsizeof(d)
524              #size of same dictionary 'd' in bytes (which is different then above)
```

2) with list:-

```
from sys import getsizeof
l = range(20)
l.__sizeof__()   
100           #size of list 'l' in bytes

getsizeof(l)
116           #size of same list 'l' in bytes
```

3) with tuple:-

```
from sys import getsizeof
t = tuple(range(20))
t.__sizeof__()
92             #size of tuple 't' in bytes

getsizeof(t)
108            #size of same tuple 't' in bytes
```

Would anyone tell me why this kind of behaviour, when documentation of both function says that they return size of object in bytes.

Answer (score 4):

From the [sys docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> getsizeof() calls the object’s **sizeof** method **and adds an
>   additional garbage collector overhead** if the object is managed by the
>   garbage collector.

I'm guessing that explains the discrepancy.